# Inserting a list of ids to a complex json object

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a list of product ids, that I want to add a to a pandas dataframe after scrape. Here's my code:

```
all_products = df.tolist()
sample_products = all_products[0:2] # ['00001', '00002']
results = []

for idx, x in enumerate(sample_products):
    url = f"https://api.ourcompany.com/product/{x}/products"
    querystring = {"some_query"}
    headers = {"cookie": "some_stuff"}
    r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    try:
        data = r.json()
        for p in data['obj']:
            results.append(p)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, flush = True)

    print(idx, len(results))

    df = pd.json_normalize(results)
```

Output df looks like this:

| product_type | product_sales |
| --- | --- |
| car | $50 |
| bike | $20 |

I want to add the product id `x` from the loop to the dataframe to look something like this. How do i do it? I've been spinning over my head over this.

| product_id | product_type | product_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | car | $50 |
| 00002 | bike | $20 |

Comment: how about `df['product_id'] = range(1, 3)` and later reformat it to string `df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)`

Comment: I don't understand why you show `requests` in question.

Answer (score 0):

First you can assign integer values using `range()`

```
df['product_id'] = range(1, 3)
```

And later you can convert them to strings and fill with zeros

```
df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

or

```
df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:05s}')
```

---

Or you can use `list comprehension` to create list with strings

```
df['product_id'] = [str(x).zfill(5) for x in range(1, 3)]
```

or

```
df['product_id'] = [f'{x:05s}' for x in range(1, 3)]
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product_type': ['car', 'bike'],                     
    'product_sales': ['$50', '$20'],
})
print(df)

# --- version 1 ---

df['product_id'] = range(1, 3)
print(df)

df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
#df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:05s}')
print(df)


# --- version 2 ---

df['product_id'] = [str(x).zfill(5) for x in range(1, 3)]
#df['product_id'] = [f'{x:05s}' for x in range(1, 3)]
print(df)

# --- change order ---

df = df[['product_id', 'product_type', 'product_sales']]
print(df)
```

Result:

```
  product_type product_sales
0          car           $50
1         bike           $20

  product_type product_sales  product_id
0          car           $50           1
1         bike           $20           2

  product_type product_sales product_id
0          car           $50      00001
1         bike           $20      00002

  product_type product_sales product_id
0          car           $50      00001
1         bike           $20      00002

  product_id product_type product_sales
0      00001          car           $50
1      00002         bike           $20
```